# How can I use enum variants as generic type?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to use enum as type variant over a generic struct.

This gives me a error:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Role {
    User,
    Admin,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Session<T> {
    id: i64,
    role: T,
}

fn only_for_user(s: Session<Role::User>) {
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn only_for_admin(s: Session<Role::Admin>) {
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let session = Session {
        id: 1,
        role: Role::User,
    };
    only_for_user(session);
}
```

```
error[E0573]: expected type, found variant `Role::User`
  --> src/main.rs:13:29
   |
13 | fn only_for_user(s: Session<Role::User>) {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^
   |                             |
   |                             not a type
   |                             help: try using the variant's enum: `crate::Role`

error[E0573]: expected type, found variant `Role::Admin`
  --> src/main.rs:17:30
   |
17 | fn only_for_admin(s: Session<Role::Admin>) {
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                              |
   |                              not a type
   |                              help: try using the variant's enum: `crate::Role`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fa849b522dfd28f11ad3d02aea0b4586).

Comment: Please always post the full error, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot do that. Enum variants are not types themselves ([there was an RFC for that](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450), however [it was postponed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450#issuecomment-271042602)).

The usual way to do such thing is to have a struct that contains the variant data and to make the variant contain this struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct User;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Admin;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Role {
    User(User),
    Admin(Admin),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Session<T> {
    id: i64,
    role: T,
}

fn only_for_user(s: Session<User>) {
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn only_for_admin(s: Session<Admin>) {
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let session = Session {
        id: 1,
        role: User,
    };
    only_for_user(session);
}
```

You can tie the enum and the structs together with traits.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the role of the `enum` in your example. As far as I understand it, it's never used. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BlackBeans Yes, it is not used in this example, but it was meant to demonstrate the idea of an enum with variants that are structs. In real example it may be used (or there is no reason to use `enum` in the first place).

Comment: @Finomnis I suppose there is a reason the OP needs an enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do that with trait.

```rust
trait Role: std::fmt::Debug {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct User;
impl Role for User {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Admin;
impl Role for Admin {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Session<T: Role> {
    id: i64,
    role: T,
}

fn only_for_user(s: Session<User>) {
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn only_for_admin(s: Session<Admin>) {
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let session = Session {
        id: 1,
        role: User {},
    };
    only_for_user(session);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).