In Rust, what is the idiomatic way to associate members of one enum with other enum types and map between their integer and string representations?
Goal:

I'd like to turn a pair of (usagePage, usageID) integers to Rust enumeration variants and get the names of both the page and specific usages as strings for debugging purposes.
I'd like to define this in the most idiomatic way.
I'd like to reuse the enums provided by the usbd_human_interface_device::page module.
I'd like this mapping to fail gracefully - that is, given integers out of range of both enums, I'd like to detect that and return strings indicating that the mapping was not found.

This failure case could be a failure to look up the usagePage or a failure to look up the usageID within the correct enumeration.



Concrete:

I'm using the enum types from usbd_human_interface_device::page, namely Consumer, Desktop, Game and the like.

These enums have a numeric primitive association for each variant. For example, Desktop::SystemPowerDown is 129.


That library does not provide an enum for each page, so I've written HIDPage below.
I'd like to turn a pair of integers into a HIDPage variant and the associated page-specific varient, such as Desktop::SystemPowerDown
Each of those enum types are used when a HIDPage numeric enum variant specifies to do so. That is, given the tuple of integers (1, 129) I'd like to return (HIDPage::Desktop,Desktop::SystemPowerDown).

Challenges:

The type of enumeration must be determined at runtime, as the enum to look up depends on an integer that is not known until then.

This implies that the second return value is generic over the set of enums I'd like to return, but I'm not sure how to write that. I tried defining a new trait that each enum implements but I couldn't get that working.


I'd like to return the enum type directly, but I think that's not possible as enums are not types. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72438660/84041 seemed to have a similar question, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.
I'd like to not be overly verbose in this mapping - I have a solution below, but it seems overly verbose. Is there a better way to write this?

Abstract:

Is this the most idiomatic way to do this in Rust?

// My HIDPage enum implementation
use num_enum::{TryFromPrimitive};

#[repr(u16)]
#[derive(
    Debug,
    Copy,
    Clone,
    Eq,
    PartialEq,
    Ord,
    PartialOrd,
    Hash,
    TryFromPrimitive,
)]
pub enum HIDPage {
    Desktop = 1,
    Simulation = 2,
    Game = 5,
    Keyboard = 7,
    Telephony = 0x0b,
    Consumer = 0x0c,
}

use usbd_human_interface_device::page::*;

// This enumeration, plus HIDPage, seem overly verbose
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum HIDEnum {
    Desktop(Desktop),
    Simulation(Simulation),
    Game(Game),
    Keyboard(Keyboard),
    Telephony(Telephony),
    Consumer(Consumer),
}


fn new_usage_from_ints(page:u16 , id: u16) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let knownPage: Option<HIDPage> = HIDPage::try_from(page as u16).ok();

    if let Some(knownPage) = knownPage.as_ref() {
        let knownId: Option<HIDEnum> = match knownPage {
            // Each line requires repeating the type (in different contexts) three times
            HIDPage::Desktop => Desktop::try_from(id as u8).ok().map(|v| HIDEnum::Desktop(v)),
            HIDPage::Simulation => Simulation::try_from(id as u8).ok().map(|v| HIDEnum::Simulation(v)),
            HIDPage::Game => Game::try_from(id as u8).ok().map(|v| HIDEnum::Game(v)),
            HIDPage::Keyboard => Keyboard::try_from(id as u8).ok().map(|v| HIDEnum::Keyboard(v)),
            HIDPage::Telephony => Telephony::try_from(id as u8).ok().map(|v| HIDEnum::Telephony(v)),
            HIDPage::Consumer => Consumer::try_from(id as u16).ok().map(|v| HIDEnum::Consumer(v)),
        };
        return Ok(format!("nui {:?}/{:?} (0x{:x}/0x{:x})", knownPage, knownId, page, id));
    }
    return Ok(format!("nui {:?} (0x{:x}/0x{:x})", knownPage, page, id));
}



"type of enumeration must be determined at runtime ... implies that the second return value is generic over the set of enums I'd like to return" This is a fundamental misunderstanding of generics. Generics only exist at compile time. Creating a new enum with a variant for each enum you might return is exactly the idiomatic solution.

But a better solution for your case might be to have an enum HID with all those variants, and manually implement TryFrom<(page, id)>

In "generic over the set" I meant in abstract non-rust semantics - I'm aware Rust generics only exist at compile time (and are monomorphized when used).
In terms of implementing TryFrom<(page, id)>, I'd imagine you'd suggest that the implementation would more or less be what I have as the implementation here of new_usage_from_ints, right? (excluding the string conversions, of course)
Thanks for the confirmation that this is idiomatic - why not post as an answer so I can accept it?

A better solution may be to have just the HIDEnum (called just HID below) and manually implement TryFrom or just have an inherent function for it.
pub enum HID {
    Desktop(Desktop),
    Simulation(Simulation),
    Game(Game),
    Keyboard(Keyboard),
    Telephony(Telephony),
    Consumer(Consumer),
}

impl HID {
    pub fn parse(page: u16, id: u16) -> Result<HID, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let out = match page {
            1 => HID::Desktop(Desktop::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            2 => HID::Simulation(Simulation::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            5 => HID::Game(Game::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            7 => HID::Keyboard(Keyboard::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            0x0b => HID::Telephony(Telephony::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            0x0c => HID::Consumer(Consumer::try_from(id)?),
            _ => Err(UnknownPageError)?,
        };
        Ok(out)
    }
}

But if you want to keep things more declarative, you can use a separate enum for the page ID and map from that to HID:
#[repr(u16)]
#[derive(
    Debug,
    Copy,
    Clone,
    Eq,
    PartialEq,
    Ord,
    PartialOrd,
    Hash,
    TryFromPrimitive,
)]
pub enum PageId {
    Desktop = 1,
    Simulation = 2,
    Game = 5,
    Keyboard = 7,
    Telephony = 0x0b,
    Consumer = 0x0c,
}

impl HID {
    pub fn parse2(page: u16, id: u16) -> Result<HID, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let page = PageId::try_from(page)?;

        let out = match page {
            PageId::Desktop => HID::Desktop(Desktop::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            PageId::Simulation => HID::Simulation(Simulation::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            PageId::Game => HID::Game(Game::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            PageId::Keyboard => HID::Keyboard(Keyboard::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            PageId::Telephony => HID::Telephony(Telephony::try_from(u8::try_from(id)?)?),
            PageId::Consumer => HID::Consumer(Consumer::try_from(id)?),
        };
        Ok(out)
    }
}

